# Do these have the same meaning: "...finding out what his life has been like." VS "...finding out how his life has been."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**"She spends time with him finding out what his life has been like.**"

The question structure **"What something is like"** seems to have the same meaning with **"how something is?"** when it comes to the objects (not persons). So, I think I can simply say:

**"She spends time with him finding out how his life has been.**"

Am I right in my thinking?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.  **what his life has been like** is more or less synonymous with **how his life has been**.  However, you should note that "what [something] is like" is not a question form.  The question form would be "What is [something] like?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what his life has been like** is idiomatic. It is how a native speaker might refer to another person's ups and downs, challenges, successes, failures, health, family, job situation, and so on.

> I asked him **what his life had been like**.
>
> I asked him **how he had been**.
>
> I asked him **how his life had been**.

All three are perfectly grammatical.  To my ear, however, asking  someone "what their life has been like" suggests more probing sorts of questions or a wider range of questions than is implied by "how his life had been". The former wants *details* whereas a person asking "How has your life been?" might be content to receive "I've been doing quite well" as an answer. They both refer to *life*, which is broad in scope; the nuance is carried  by **like**.

But many speakers might hear no such nuance in **like** and treat it as a throwaway word, and they might hear these examples as nearly identical:

> I hear you took a road trip from Florida to Oregon. Tell me what it was like.
>
> I hear you took a road trip from Florida to Oregon. Tell me how it was.

> I hear you've been to their production of *The Tempest*. What was it like?
>
> I hear you've been to their production of *The Tempest*. How was it?